# Symfony 5 @required annotation weird caching issue during setter injection?

Tags: apache, docker, symfony, caching, annotations

I discovered this strange issue in Symfony 5 which I believe is connected to docker and Symfony itself.

## MY SETUP

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: ./php/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: webapp
    image: php:7.4.1-fpm-alpine
    volumes:
      - ../:/srv/app
  apache2:
    build:
      network: host
      context: ./apache2/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: apache2
    image: httpd:2.4.39-alpine
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ../:/srv/app
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 13306:3306
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql:cached
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: XXX
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: XXX
      MYSQL_DATABASE: XXX
      MYSQL_USER: XXX
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: XXX
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:5.0.6-alpine
    ports:
      - 16379:6379
    volumes:
      - redis:/data:cached

volumes:
  mysql:
    driver: local
  redis:
    driver: local
```

For framework I am of course using Symfony 5. I am quite sure this setup is correct because I am using something like that for my other Laravel project and it is working very well.

## THE PROBLEM

On my trait I am using `@required` annotation. To be more exact I am using that on a setter like this:

```
    /**
     * Get the current request out of RequestStack object.
     *
     * @param RequestStack $requestStack
     * @required
     */
    public function setRequest(RequestStack $requestStack): void
    {
        $this->currentRequest = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    }
```

I know this bit is fine as it always worked in previous version. The problem seems to be in `@required` annotation. I am not sure why but every time I add it I get:

[image]

It looks like there is something wrong with the server, however as soon as I manually clear the cache it works and then after another call (and changing something in code and in postman call like query parameter's content) it breaks again until I either remove `@required` or clear the cache.

I am confused - I am not sure if it is to do with my docker setup or there is a bug in Symfony's caching mechanism or maybe it is combination off all of my suspicions and even more.

My bet would be a bug in Symfony caching or there is something wrong with how I set up the docker. However I just started working on that, I don't even connect to the database at this point, these are literally first steps in rewriting that project so nothing funky is happening.

What do you think guys? Did anyone see something like that before?

## WHAT DID I TRY

I did try clear cache, removing and adding that annotation I did try rebooting my docker, I did prune the whole thing and made brand new setup. Nothing worked so far.

## UPDATE 30.01.2020 19:45

I did try the same setter injection directly on the controller and I can't reproduce the error. I think that for some reason it doesn't like it on the trait.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that your code worked in the past since the RequestStack is often injected before the request itself is available.  Depends of course on when the service is created.  This is just a guess but you might try storing the request stack and then pulling the request when it is actually needed.  But I admit my guess does not explain the symptoms.

Comment: @Cerad - thanks for your reply. I did double check with my old code. Exactly the same (minus PHP 7 features). I also fallowed your advice - I checked what is going to happen if I will inject it someplace else. It is a bit weird - the same setter injection with `@required` works fine directly on controller but it doesn't work on the trait. 503 makes it even stranger - it has nothing to do with php but with server state. I am keen to keep it like that because this trait is supposed to sit on my ApiController. Your advice however made me aware that is doesn't like it on the trait anymore.

Comment: @Cerad - just to add, there is definitely something going on with cache. I am injecting in my trait request twice and it breaks(but sometimes works I can't figure out what is the rule here).  It seems to be always working when I inject it only once. I am not sure if I should open a ticket on the Symfony's Github page.

Comment: It sort of sound like a preload issue.  You might try php 7.4.2 which is suppose to fix at least some of the Symfony preload issues.

Comment: @Cerad - ahh - you are right. Now that you said it I do recall seeing something about symonfy on the list of bug fixes on PHP website. I will check that out tomorrow probably(long day ahead of me today) and I will let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem is an upgrade. Like Cerad mentioned in his comment - updating PHP from 7.4.1 to 7.4.2 could solve the problem and it did.

If you are on Symfony 5 make sure you have PHP 7.4.2 to avoid this particular issue.